# Existence of an "Orthogonalizing" Operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra

I was wondering if it was possible to prove existence of a unitary operator $A$ such that:
$\langle Au,u\rangle=0$ for all $u$.
In 2-dimensions it clearly is (just a 90 degrees rotation) and similarly in other finite dimensions. However is it possible to prove this for infinite dimensions?
For all $u\in L^{2}$, say?

Comment: What other conditions are you putting on A? for instance, is it allowed to have non-trivial kernel? (I assume not but you should make your assumptions/conditions more clear)

Comment: Yes sorry I realized this after I posted. A non-trivial kernel indeed. In fact it would be nice to know that this is possible for a unitary operator A.

Comment: Are you working in real or complex space? If the former, in dimension three the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is odd and therefore has a real root, which implies the existence of a one-dimensional invariant subspace. If the latter then the existence of a one-dimensional invariant subspace also holds even in dimension two. The desired property clearly cannot hold in the presence of a one-dimensional invariant subspace which does not lie in the kernel.

Comment: Ah yes, should have mentioned I'm working in real space.

Comment: Ah yes, thankyou very much I had overlooked the case of spaces of odd dimension. But even so my question is really whether or not such an operator exists in infinite dimensional space. I'm starting to think this may not be as trivial as I had hoped.

Comment: What about taking an orthogonal splitting $H=H_1\oplus H_2$, with $H_i$ both isomorphic to $H$, an isometry $B:H_1\to H_2$, and set $A=[0\; -B^*;B\; 0]$ ($2\times 2$ block matrix) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find such an operator in separable real Hilbert space just take a countable direct sum of rotations of $\mathbb{R}^2$. More formally:

Let $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable basis for Hilbert space and define an operator $A$ by $Ae_{2n}=e_{2n+1}$ and $Ae_{2n+1}=-e_{2n}$. If $u=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_ke_k$ where the $a_k$'s are real then we have $Au=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{2n}e_{2n+1}-a_{2n+1}e_{2n})$ and so $\langle Au, u\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{2n+1}a_{2n}-a_{2n}a_{2n+1})=0$. If the coefficients are allowed to be complex then the minus becomes a plus in the imaginary component and we will typically get a nonzero answer due to the effect of complex conjugation in the definition of inner product.

As I mentioned in the comments, for real matrices of odd finite dimension the characteristic polynomial of $A$ will have a real root, which implies the existence of an invariant subspace. If the corresponding eigenvalue is nonzero then the relation $\langle Au, u\rangle=0$ is obviously impossible when $u$ belongs to this eigenspace, so in odd dimensions this property is impossible for an invertible matrix $A$. This same observation means that the desired property also does not hold for any invertible complex matrix.